# How to enable SSL/TSL to a non-web port in AWS

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2

I installed a server on AWS EC2, which listens at several ports including ssh=22, http=80 and some others non-web ports. for http=80, I make it secure by wrapping it with a route53 domain->Application load balancer->https:443 ->target group->http:80 so that end user accessing https://domain will then be forwarded to port 80.

How to make other ports secured with SSL/TLS? Note they are not web server ports.

I tried to create a SSL based TCP load balancer to listen and forward traffic to the port. but when I "Request a certificate" in AWS certificate manager (in ordered to create SSL based load balancer I have to create certificate in ACM) it asked me to input domain name, while this port is not web server port so it does not have domain name...

What is the setup to make the non-web port secured with SSL/TLS?

Comment: A domain name is a friendly name thats transitioned into an ip address. domain names are used to access the websites, it does not mean you cannot access a domain name via other protocols for `e.g sftp://sftp.mydomain.com:22`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A domain name is a friendly name that represents one or more ip addresses. domain names are often used to access the websites, it does not mean that you cannot use a domain name to access non web services via other protocols for `e.g sftp://sftp.mydomain.com:22`

Therefore technically you should be able load balance non web traffic using a load balancer.

in regards to requesting a certificate in ACM, You can specify a subdomain of your existing domain for e.g `sftp.example.com` or you can get a wildcard certificate (`*.example.com`) that can be used for any subdomains.

Once you have the load balancer created, you can create and point a subdomain to your load balancer dns name.

Hope this helps

Comment: Arun K: Thanks. I already have https://subdomain.domain.com to forward 443 to 80, can I reuse the same subdomain.domain.com to forward that non-web protocol. e.g, e.g. forward subdomain.domain.com:8050 to port 8050? then what protocol should enduser write in front of the url? it is not https (which is for 443) and it is not sftp.

Comment: yes you can. what user the end user write in front of  url is based on what service is serving from that port